# The next code always returns false for some reason when it shouldn't

Tags: java

**supposed to return true if the first half of an array is equal to the second but it keeps return false... I tried debugging but still doesn't work... Help!**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3};

        System.out.println(sda(arr));

    }//main

    public static boolean sda(int[] arr) {

        int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
        int[] arr3 = new int[arr.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < (arr2.length/2); i++) {
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        }
        for(int i = arr.length - 1; i > (arr.length/2) - 1; i--) {
            arr3[i] = arr[i];
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length/2 - 1; j++) {
            if(arr3[j] != arr2[j]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static boolean sda(int[] arr) {
    
    for(int i=0, j=arr.length/2; i<arr.length/2 || j<arr.length; i++, j++)
        if(arr[i]!=arr[j])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You might want to do an initial check for an odd length for the array ``if ((arr.length % 2) == 1) return false``.

Comment: @pks - Why didn't you write int j = arr.length/2? I copied your code and tried to do it with int and it didn't work for some reason, why is that?

Comment: If you have do initialization of multiple variables or manipulation of multiple variables, you can achieve it by separating them with comma(,) in for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Emmm... Well, a good resolve method is to debug on the value of

```
arr2
```

and

```
arr3
```

. Then you'll find this:

```
int arr2[] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0};
int arr3[] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Come on! Do it and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If I break down the current code:
First arr2 and arr3 are assigned an empty array of 6 items.
Next arr2 is assigned values (1,2,3) in the first 3 elements of the array.
Then arr3 is assigned (1,2,3) in the final 3 elements of the array.
If I add the below code snipper under the 2nd for-loop:

```
        System.out.println("arr2: ");
        for(int i : arr2){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        System.out.println("arr3: ");
        for(int i : arr3){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

You will see that that the two arays are different.

```
arr2: 
1
2
3
0
0
0
arr3: 
0
0
0
1
2
3
```

To make the result return true, you could adjust where the arr2 values are placed or adjust where the arr3 values are placed within the array.
An alternative solution would be to change the evaluation of the two array values in the final for-loop to be:

```
for(int j = 0; j < arr.length/2 - 1; j++) {
            if(arr3[j + (arr.length/2)] != arr2[j]) return false;
        }
```

This way the evaluation of the two loops will be for the first 3 values of arr2 against the final 3 values of arr3.
In summary, I have changed the sda method to below:

```
  public static boolean sda(int[] arr) {

        int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
        int[] arr3 = new int[arr.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < (arr2.length/2); i++) {
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        }
        for(int i = arr.length - 1; i > (arr.length/2) - 1; i--) {
            arr3[i] = arr[i];
        }
        
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length/2 - 1; j++) {
            if(arr3[j + (arr.length/2)] != arr2[j]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```